# Set Individual Elements of Multidimensional Vectors in Racket

Tags: matrix, vector, racket

For a university project i have to make a game based in a matrix in the pretty big language, the matrix is being defined as a multidimensional vector.
I need to set a single element of the matrix, my code is:

```
(require racket/vector)

(define test (make-vector 4 (make-vector 4 0)))

(define (matrix-set matrix row column value)
   (vector-set! (vector-ref matrix row) column value)
)
(display test)(newline)
(matrix-set test 0 0 1)
(display test)
```

And outputs this:

```
#(#(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0))
#(#(1 0 0 0) #(1 0 0 0) #(1 0 0 0) #(1 0 0 0))
```

I have searched the racket documentation and only found functions that set an element by making a new matrix, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641644/scheme-racket-vector-in-vector-tranformation?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009590/racket-y-way-on-multidimensional-vectors-operation?lq=1) questions too.

Why is the function setting the whole column instead of only the element?

What can be done to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(make-vector 4 (make-vector 4 0))` is the same as:

```
(let ((x (make-vector 4 0)))
  (vector x x x x))
```

That is, `(make-vector 4 0)` is called only once, and its value is used for all 4 slots of the outer vector.

What you need is something like `(for/vector ((i 4)) (make-vector 4 0))`, which will call `(make-vector 4 0)` (and create a distinct vector) for each element of the outer vector.

Comment: Instead of writing `#(#0=#(0 0 0 0) #0# #0# #0#)`, which is very confusing, would it be better to write something like `(define o1 (vector 0 0 0 0))` and then write that the `test` vector is `(vector o1 o1 o1 o1)`, to explain that each `o1` points to the same object?

Comment: @AlexKnauth Thanks, that makes sense. I was trying to explain the concept of object aliasing and clearly I wasn't doing a fantastic job of it. :-)

Comment: That's also how it's explained in the [Objects and Imperative Update](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._.Objects_and_.Imperative_.Update%29) section of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that isn't what i'm asking. The question is why my function to modify the elements is modifying all the column.

Comment: @Daniel My answer explains why: all your columns are actually aliased to the same object. I also provided a solution.

Comment: So instead of making a vector of vectors, i made a vector of references to the same vector?

Comment: @Daniel Pretty much.

Comment: So the vector is the problem, the function that sets the element is ok?

Comment: Might this be a case where the familiarity of iteration makes for greater code clarity than thunking?

Comment: @benrudgers Thanks! Implemented.

Comment: I added an answer after griping about yours. I think showing the thunk is useful.

Comment: racket says for/vector isn't defined, but i managed to solve this thanks to you.

Comment: @DanielP. Which version of Racket are you running? Are you using `#lang racket` or one of the teaching languages?

Comment: @benrudgers The question already says he's using Pretty Big; I just didn't know that Pretty Big doesn't have `for*` and I didn't bother to check. :-P Of course, Pretty Big doesn't have `thunk*` either.

Comment: Missed that. I'd never noticed "pretty big" in DrRacket before.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use the vector generating iterator [`for/vector`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Fvector%29%29). I'm not sure the syntax is any cleaner than using thunks, but conceptually, I feel it is more familiar and perhaps simpler.

```
(define test (for/vector ([i (range 4)])(make-vector 4 0)))

(matrix-set test 0 0 1)  ; '#(#(1 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0) #(0 0 0 0))
```

A third alternative, that isn't as Racket like, would be using [`do`.](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-7.html?q=do#%25_idx_140)

```
(define test
  (do ((vec (make-vector 4))
       (i 0 (+ i 1)))
      ((= i 4) vec)
    (vector-set! vec i (make-vector 4 0))))
```

On the other hand, sometimes it's worth knowing a bit about `do` because `do` don't require memorizing a different command for each type since `do` does what it does on vectors, lists, and hashes.